# looping through `ls` results in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Does any one have a template shell script for doing something with `ls` for a list of directory names and looping through each one and doing something?

I'm planning to do `ls -1d */` to get the list of directory names.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

**Edited not to use ls where a glob would do, as @shawn-j-goff and others suggested.**

Just use a `for..do..done` loop:

```
for f in *; do
  echo "File -> $f"
done
```

You can replace the `*` with `*.txt` or any other glob that returns a list (of files, directories, or anything for that matter), a command that generates a list, e.g., `$(cat filelist.txt)`, or actually replace it with a list.

Within the `do` loop, you just refer to the loop variable with the dollar sign prefix (so `$f` in the above example). You can `echo` it or do anything else to it you want.

For example, to rename all the `.xml` files in the current directory to `.txt`:

```
for x in *.xml; do 
  t=$(echo $x | sed 's/\.xml$/.txt/'); 
  mv $x $t && echo "moved $x -> $t"
done
```

Or even better, if you are using Bash you can use Bash parameter expansions rather than spawning a subshell:

```
for x in *.xml; do 
  t=${x%.xml}.txt
  mv $x $t && echo "moved $x -> $t"
done
```

Comment: What if the filename has a space in it?

Comment: I'm iterating all folders.

Comment: Unfortunately, as Daniel said, the code in this answer will break if any of the files or folders contains a space or newline in their name. It shows a very common misuse of `for` loops, and a typical pitfall of trying to parse the output of `ls`. @DanielA.White, you *might* consider unaccepting this answer if it wasn't helpful (or is potentially misleading), since like you said, you're acting on directories. Shawn J. Goff's answer should provide a more robust and working solution to your issue.

Comment: -∞ [You shouldn't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), [you shouldn't read output in a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), you should use `$()` instead of `` and [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). I'm sure @CoverosGene meant well, but this is just terrible.

Comment: A better alternative if you really want to use `ls` is `ls -1 | while read line; do stuff; done`. At least that one won't break for whitespaces.

Comment: with `mv -v` you don't need `echo "moved $x -> $t"`

Comment: What if we want to use some of the options of ls?

Comment: @DanielA.White for filenames with spaces, use quotes <br/>for f in *; do for f in *; do echo "File -> " "$f" ; done

Comment: I'm a heretic. 99.999% of the time I write shell scripts, they operate with/on files under my purview (and: your situation might not be the same). So I don't care if there are spaces in the filename, because the failure is naming the file incorrectly. This is actually the same as the `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` nonsense which answers, "But what if there is a newline in the filename?". The answer is to not use spaces or newlines in your files, and you don't need to add all this ceremony. Yes, HERETICAL.

Comment: @DanielA.White - then just rename it ^_^

Comment: unfortunately this is lacking once you want to do some more advanced things that ls can do, like sort by age.

Answer (score 85):

[Using the output of `ls` to get filenames is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It can lead to malfunctioning and even dangerous scripts. This is because a filename can contain any character except `/` and the `null`character, and `ls` does not use either of those characters as delimiters, so if a filename has a space or a newline, you *will* get unexpected results.

There are two very good ways of iterating over files. Here, I've used simply `echo` to demonstrate doing something with the filename; you can use anything, though.

The first is to use the shell's native globbing features.

```
for dir in */; do
  echo "$dir"
done
```

The shell expands `*/` into separate arguments that the `for` loop reads; even if there is a space, newline, or any other strange character in the filename, `for` will see each complete name as an atomic unit; it's not parsing the list in any way.

If you want to go recursively into subdirectories, then this won't do unless your shell has some extended globbing features (such as `bash`'s `globstar`. If your shell doesn't have these features, or if you want to ensure that your script will work on a variety of systems, then the next option is to use `find`.

```
find . -type d -exec echo '{}' \;
```

Here, the `find` command will call `echo` and pass it an argument of the filename. It does this once for each file it finds. As with the previous example, there is no parsing of a list of filenames; instead, a fileneame is sent completely as an argument.

The syntax of the `-exec` argument looks a little funny. `find` takes the first argument after `-exec` and treats that as the program to run, and every subsequent argument, it takes as an argument to pass to that program. There are two special arguments that `-exec` needs to see. The first one is `{}`; this argument gets replaced with a filename that the previous parts of `find` generates. The second one is `;`, which lets `find` know this is the end of the list of arguments to pass to the program; `find` needs this because you can continue with more arguments that are intended for `find` and not intended for the exec'd program. The reason for the `\` is that the shell also treats `;` specially - it represents the end of a command, so we need to escape it so that the shell gives it as an argument to `find` rather than consuming it for itself; another way of getting the shell to not treat it specially is to put it in in quotes: `';'` works just as well as `\;` for this purpose.

Comment: +1 this is definitely the way to go when you need to generate a file list and use it in a command. find -exec is limited by only being able to run a single commands. With the loop, you can pipe to your heart's content.

Comment: +1.  I wish more people would use `find`.  There is magic that can be done, and even the perceived limitations of `-exec` can be worked around.  The `-print0` option is also valuable for use with `xargs`.

Comment: The loop option won't show hidden directories. The find option won´t show symlinks.

Comment: The problem with this approach is you also get the '.' directory back. That means if you are trying to do, for example, an `rm` of a set of subfolders, you will remove those subfolders before traversing into them. I realize this is a specific issue I am trying to solve, but worth pointing out in case anyone attempts to use this with `rm`.

Answer (score 39):

For files with spaces in you will have to make sure to quote the variable like:

```
 for i in $(ls); do echo "$i"; done;
```

or, you can change the input field separator (IFS) environment variable:

```
 (IFS=$'\n';for i in $(ls); do echo $i; done) # subshell to restore IFS
```

Finally, depending on what you're doing, you may not even need the ls:

```
 for i in *; do echo "$i"; done;
```

Comment: nice use of a subshell in the first example

Comment: Why does IFS need a $ after the assignment and before the new character?

Comment: Filenames can also contain newlines.  Breaking on `\n` is insufficient.  It's never a good idea to recommend parsing the output of `ls`.

Comment: Could replace \n with \0 (null character), as some people have suggested

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
ls | parallel echo {} is in this dir
```

To rename all .txt to .xml:

```
ls *.txt | parallel mv {} {.}.xml
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to CoverosGene's answer, here is a way to list just the directory names:

```
for f in */; do
  echo "Directory -> $f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not set IFS to a newline, then capture the output of `ls` in an array?  Setting IFS to newline should resolve issues with funny characters in file names; using `ls` can be nice because it has a built-in sort facility.

(In testing I was having trouble setting IFS to `\n` but setting it to newline backspace works, as suggested elsewhere here):

E.g. (assuming desired `ls` search pattern passed in `$1`):

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

FILES=($(/bin/ls "$1"))

for AFILE in ${FILES[@]}
do
    ... do something with a file ...
done

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

This is especially handy on OS X, e.g., to capture a list of files sorted by creation date (oldest to newest), the `ls` command is `ls -t -U -r`.

Comment: Filenames can also contain newlines, and they often do when users are permitted to name their own files.  Breaking on `\n` is insufficient.  The only valid solutions use a for loop with pathname expansion, or `find`.

Comment: The only reliable way to transfer a list of file names is to separate them with a NUL character, as this is the only one definitely not contained in a file path.

Answer (score 2):

while loop with ls command  in a command line

```
ls | while read filename;do echo "file name is $filename"; done
```

Answer (score -3):

This is how I do it, but there are probably more efficient ways.

```
ls > filelist.txt

while read filename; do echo filename: "$filename"; done < filelist.txt
```

Comment: Stick to pipes in place of the file:

>`ls | while read i; do echo filename: $i; done`

Comment: Cool. I should say that you can also use $EDITOR filelist.txt in between the two commands. Lots of stuff you can do in an editor that is easier than on the command line. Not relevant to this question, though.

Comment: Your solution doesn't at all address the problem with file names containing newlines and other fancy stuff.

Answer (score -3):

It's prefectly fine:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `ls`
do
   echo `ls -l $i`
done
```

Here is the output:

```
root@online:/usr/local/httpd/bin # more ~root/rm-in-ls.sh
    #!/bin/sh
    for i in `ls` 
    do
      echo `ls -l $i`
    done

root@online:/usr/local/httpd/bin # /root/rm-in-ls.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 82516 Jul 3 04:52 ab
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 40 3431 Jul 3 04:35 apachectl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 40 23881 Jul 3 04:35 apxs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 21456 Jul 3 04:52 checkgid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 40 8931 Jul 3 04:35 dbmmanage
root@online:/usr/local/httpd/bin #
```

Missed it ! Right !!!

HEADS UP !!!

Thats not " ' " in 'ls' !!!
Thats " ` " in `ls`.
The acute not apostrophe.
There is a difference between ' and `.
I spent a week on that to figure out when I was in college (1990).

This is "`", the key with ~ Tilde mostly shift + ~, it's called acute.[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent)

If you did not get it, then copy and paste the script and run.

Comment: It doesn't play well with spaces in files/folders names. The problem is not in the quote.

Comment: I am bit surprised that I got -2 on a perfect and notable example that I learned from mistake as student at my college life decades ago. Surprised that not many experts around for up vote.